# iMacro + JS slows down and consumes too much memory

Tags: javascript, imacros

I coded a macro that traverses through the search results in a web page, opens each link in a new tab, reads a certain text in that new tab and searches for a specific word. then closes the tab and goes on to the next link on the initial tab.

The problem is that after maybe 100 opened and closed tabs, it gets slow, and Firefox swallows memory (~2GB). It seems like those opened-then-closed tabs are not removed from the memory. But I am not sure if that is the case. Any Ideas?

```
for(var loop = 1; loop <= 200; loop++){
        iim = "CODE:\n";
        iim+="TAB T=1\n";
        iim+="TAG POS=" + loop + " TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Abstract EXTRACT=HREF\n";
        iim+="TAB OPEN\n";
        iim+="TAB T=2\n";
        iimPlay(iim);
        link = iimGetExtract(); // get the link to open in new tab

        var successful = -1;
        while(successful < 1){ // reload the link in new tab, until successful.
            iim = "CODE:\n";
            iim+="URL GOTO="+link+"\n";
            successful =  iimPlay(iim);
        }
        {
        ...searchInNewPage();
        }
        iim = "CODE:\n";
        iim+="TAB CLOSE\n";
        iimPlay(iim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whether you are using Version 9.0.3 version, if so my advice iMacros to immediately replace the previous versions of Version 8.9.7, I've mecobanya own that iMacros v 9.0.3 heavier in running script .iiim and .js